# Load balance multiple routers / wan / gateways over openwrt

Tags: networking, router

I have got two routers. One for DSL(slow, dualstack) and one for Cable(fast, ds-lite) Internet.

DSL: AVM Fritzbox 7490

- slow
- vpn server to connect to the lan
- low ping

Cable: Noname by ISP

- fast
- high ping

I have bought a third router (Linksys WRT3200acm). **Now I want to use it to load balance between the other routers**. But I want to place it freely in my LAN to have another WiFi AP.

Currently I only found following tool in openwrt:
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/mwan3
It seems to only work when the third router is placed directly behind the other two.

Is it possible to use mwan3 to load balance between the gateways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for WRT3200ACM with two internal ETH-Ports and VLAN functionality

This will work for as many routers you want, but you have got one drawback you will see later on:

**Example network**

- LEDE-Router: 192.168.0.1
- Router DSL1: 192.168.0.2 (DHCP Server off)
- Router DSL2: 192.168.0.3 (DHCP Server off)

**You will need two VLANs.**

- VLAN1 for your normal LAN connection.

  - Connect VLAN1(tagged) to ETH0 so you have got ETH0.1
  - Specifiy at least two ports as dedicated untagged VLAN1 port
- VLAN2 for your gateways

  - Connect VLAN2(tagged) to ETH0 so you have got ETH0.2 and ETH1.2
  - Specifiy at least one port as dedicated untagged VLAN2 port

**ETH Configuration**

- ETH0.1 - LEDE-Router

  - IP: 192.168.0.1
  - Subnet: 255.255.255.0
  - LAN-Zone
- ETH0.2 - Router DSL1

  - IP: 192.168.0.12
  - Subnet: 255.255.255.0
  - Gateway: 192.168.0.2
  - WAN-Zone
- ETH1.2 - Router DSL2

  - IP: 192.168.0.13
  - Subnet: 255.255.255.0
  - Gateway: 192.168.0.3
  - WAN-Zone

Now Connect a untagged VLAN1 port to your VLAN2 port to connect VLAN1 and VLAN2 physically.

Now you can configurate mwan3 to load-balance WAN1 and WAN2.