# How to connect 2 routers from 2 ISPs

Tags: router, routing, openwrt

I have connections from 2 ISPs. One router is running OpenWRT (`192.168.1.1` - Router1). All clients are currently connected to Router1. Another DSL connection running the default firmware provided. (`192.168.10.1` - Router2)

Port 4 of Router1 is connected to Port 4 of Router 2. The IPs and LAN are setup via Router1.

How do I load balance across both the routers or How can I redirect traffic for a specific set of IPs to go through Router2 instead of Router1 which is based on OpenWRT? (Router2 does not have any clients.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I load balance across both the routers

It will be easiest to use the OpenWRT router as the load-balancer. First put its port 4 in a **separate VLAN** (so that you have three networks – LAN, WAN1, and WAN2), then take a look at using the **[multiwan](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/multiwan/multiwan_package) or [mwan3](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/multiwan/mwan3)** packages.

(Your second router will just act as the WAN2 provider and will be invisible to clients – in fact, it's best if you switch it to pure "DSL modem/bridge" mode.)

There's a slightly similar [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1285620/load-balance-multiple-routers-wan-gateways-over-openwrt?rq=1) about *three* routers.

> How can I redirect traffic for a specific set of IPs to go through Router2

If you mean "for specific *destination* IPs":

Do the same "separate VLAN" config as above, but instead of using multiwan, just create a few static routes on Router1 that go through Router2, e.g. "8.8.8.8/32 via 192.168.10.1".

Comment: can you help out with a in-depth reference about VLANs? I read some basics, but none of them helped me much to understand to configure for this usecase.

Comment: VLANs are simply isolated networks. You can set your router to have 3 ports in one network and 1 port in another network. Both networks are isolated and devices in one cannot see the other. In some routers, this is called Interface grouping.

Comment: I _think_ OpenWRT just calls them "VLANs" and indeed already has two of them preconfigured on most devices (one for LAN ports, one for the WAN port). But it's been a while since I used OpenWRT, much less on a 'typical' router device.

Comment: What @grawity meant is, you can configure Router2 in bridge mode (it will bridge its DSL network with its LAN ports) and Router1 will isolate this bridged network from other devices in the network using VLAN. Your Router1 will have your DSL settings and will dial using PPPoE via its LAN4 (WAN2) port

Comment: I could not set up a bridge mode from router2 to router1 because of the settings on the router. I was able to configure the interface connected as a DHCP client and setup mwan3 to load balance across the WAN and WLAN2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to configure a *Static route* feature in your Router1, it would be pretty easy to redirect a particular set of IPs to go through Router2. For example -
[image: Static route setting example (D-Link router firmware)]

<del>Load balancing is not an easy thing, you will need to use some extra hardware or configure every device to balance load on their own.</del> @[grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686), thanks for informing about the OpenWRT MultiWAN packages. Also check out [load balancing with](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-use-pfsense-to-load-balance-your-web-servers) [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org).

If you simply want your PCs to use both internet connections without load balancing, you can do so via the Network Adaptor settings in Windows -
[image: Advanced TCP/IP settings in Windows]

Also, you don't need to keep both the routers on two different subnets, you can use **192.168.1.1** for Router1 and **192.168.1.2** for Router2. You only have to make sure that DHCP is enabled only in one of the 2 routers, otherwise you'll have problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a connection such as
"*client<=>router1<=>router2<=>ISP*", this seems inefficient and may not really
off-load the burden from router1.

Real load-balancing would be done by :

1. The clients themselves, which would require two network adapters for each one.
2. Getting one
   [load-balancing router](https://www.amazon.com/slp/load-balancing-router/v9pu9ck437yc8ov),
   also called Dual Wan, that can connect directly to both ISPs or to both routers.
   This would have the advantage of automatically distributing all the connections
   without you manually needing to specify any routes.

See also
[Best Dual Wan Router Reviewed: 7 Load Balancing Routers 2019 List](https://www.pickmyrouter.com/best-dual-wan-routers/).

Comment: Most likely, the idea is to offload the burden from the connection to ISP1, as the router itself is usually capable of carrying more traffic than the upstream connection. It sounds like OP has limited LTE + unlimited ADSL or something like that.

Comment: @grawity: This a lot of work for something that might not help. A Dual Wan router is guaranteed to help, but it costs.

Comment: How do you imagine a "Dual Wan" router differs from a regular router?

Comment: @grawity: The name says it all.

Comment: That's the thing, it doesn't. Does it have extra hardware that justifies the cost? Some expensive software? Patented algorithms?

Comment: @grawity: Today's slogan: Buyers beware. That's why I only gave links to reviews.

Comment: @harrymc, this is only for a homelab setup, hence efficiency is not a big concern it may only add less than a few milliseconds. I wanted to explore software options with openwrt. 

Router2 ISP has 2GB limit per day is more reliable because of the DSL, Router1 ISP has more bandwidth as well as speed, but could fail when there is a power failure. I wanted to see if I could setup a reliable connection without upgrading the current hardware.

Comment: Load balancing is not the right term in that case. If this is only a routing problem, it can in my opinion be done by routing commands in router1.

Comment: @harrymc, I was interested in the routing commands itself, but the openWRT's mwan3 helped out with load balancing when one interface is down or load balancing etc.,